# Install of Eclipse CDT for Lucid Lynx Fails

Tags: linux, eclipse

When I try to install the CDT (C++ Development Tools) from the [Galileo Update Site](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo/), I get the following errors below.  How do I go about fixing this?  I need CDT build and debug tools.

I installed the Eclipse platform using the software installer included with Linux Ubuntu Lucid Lynx.  I attempted to install the CDT tools using the installer that comes with Eclipse.

```
An error occurred while installing the items
  session context was:(profile=PlatformProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null --> [R]org.eclipse.cvs 1.0.400.v201002111343, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.InstallBundleAction).
  The artifact file for osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cvs,1.0.400.v201002111343 was not found.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to install eclipse-pde. In the terminal, type :

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse-pde
```

Comment: Thank you kindly...what does that do exactly or non-exactly?

Comment: You have to install the Plugin development enviroment and then you can install the desired plugin from eclipse update site ...

Comment: Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency....when I use the GUI

Comment: run : sudo apt-get install eclipse-pde from a terminal ... and post the output

Comment: No errors can I install the CDT debugger and build tools this way as well?

Comment: I used the gui for the CDT tools and all is well